# Post method confusion in play framework

Tags: java, post, get, playframework-2.0

hi everyone i am a newbie to play framework following a first tutorial of play framework i hav little confusion POST and GET in play ...

is it always necessary to  have a GET request for a Post request to happen can't we send data in post request .

routefile

```
POST         /delete_task:id         controllers.Data.deleteTask(id:String)
```

controllerfile

```
    public static Result deleteTask(String id) {
    return ok(id);
}
```

when i change it to GET method i works Can't send data in post request ! 
Thank you in advance !!!

Comment: Action not found For request 'GET /delete_task:10000as'

Comment: Show us the form which sends this request

Comment: POST and GET (and DELETE and PUT) are HTML form actions. If you have a form and you are submitting it by POST action, then use POST, otherwise use GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET         /delete_task/:id         controllers.Data.deleteTask(id:String)
```

- can be the missing '/'
- Or, since you are providing value from the URL, which isn't actually a POST behaviour
- Or, if you were really trying to send POST data then, `deleteTask(id:String)` don't need to provide **arguement type**